# Any idea on how to implement these database tables to Java?

Tags: java, mysql, database-design, jdbc

I've started to develop my own mini project in restaurant reservation to improve my Java skills.

At the moment, I create a table consists of

- number of tables in the restaurant
  (column)
- and time interval during the day
  (row).

So for example, if someone booked a table at 11:00 on Table 4, that cell will become reserved and mark as booked. And i should be able to separate the table of each day to be their own table so that i can select to view the today table or tomorrow table.

I created 3 MySQL table; 'customer', 'seat', and 'booking' table. Detail of each table in the fixture below.

**The Problem is i have the idea on what i want to do, but i have no idea on how** to bind the data from each table to the table in Netbeans. (I'm using NetBeans).

**I'm asking for your idea on how to implement this!**

Please see the images below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to improve your skills, I would recommend to take a look to basic JDBC, for it is the base of database usage on Java.
Once you have mastered that, you can go for EJB, hibernate & everything...

So now, you should read about JDBC, PreparedStatement, Connections, and if you are aiming web, Connection Pooling... ([this would be a start to JDBC](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/JDBCTutorial/index.html))

Good luck

Comment: so the only way i can implement the idea is to use the 'EJB' thing?

Comment: No, That would not be my recommendation. If you are learning Java, I would prepare classes to hold my data, and some queries & JDBC access to fill the info. Again, the link provided is quite usefull for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EJB 3 for that. Netbeans provide stubs generation from the tables you create.